# Is there a way to break up long xpath lines in Python?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I've been converting some XPath from my Perl scripts to Python. Everything is working fine but Pylint complains that the lines are too long. In Perl I use white space to make the XPath more readable by breaking up long lines.

Perl example:

```
my $node_list = $device->findnodes(
    "./templateObjects
        /TemplateObject[fieldName/text() = 'SCADAArea']
            /keyPairs
                /TemplateKeyValuePair[TemplateName/text() = '%AREA%']
                    /TemplateValue");
```

In Python:

```
node_list = device.xpath( "templateObjects/TemplateObject[fieldName/text() = 'SCADAArea']/keyPairs/TemplateKeyValuePair[TemplateName/text() = '%AREA%']/TemplateValue")
```

Is there a better way in Python? I tried triple quotes but it didn't accept the XPath like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like mentioned in a comment, just use separate strings...

```py
node_list = device.xpath("templateObjects/TemplateObject[fieldName/text() = 'SCADAArea']/keyPairs/"
                         "TemplateKeyValuePair[TemplateName/text() = '%AREA%']/TemplateValue")
```

or

```py
node_list = device.xpath("templateObjects"
                         "/TemplateObject[fieldName/text() = 'SCADAArea']"
                         "/keyPairs"
                         "/TemplateKeyValuePair[TemplateName/text() = '%AREA%']"
                         "/TemplateValue")
```